# SQLAlchemy foreign keys access optimazation

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the very simple Parent - Child (one-to-one) relationship between two tables.

When I do a look up by `ID` everything seems okay. But if I run it for 10k `IDs` it takes almost 70secs to return the result.

After my debugging I discovered that the assigning value of the foreign key to my dictionary is what takes most of the time.

```
result = {
    "name": parent.name,
    "child_name": parent.child.name
}
```

if I comment out the `"child_name"` I get the results in around 2secs (for 10k) with it takes around 70secs.

Comment: The proof is in the pudding. Try and see, and share your result as an answer to your own question.

Comment: did try the indexes, no change

Comment: In general it is always helpful to add the right indexes. You have a rather simple relationship over two tables. You should not have any problems with it when there are the right indexes. The result time of 2s is too much already and indicates, that there are no useful indexes at all.

Comment: Please post the DB structure and the indexes you have created. Also helpful would be the query SQLAlchemy constructs. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#dbengine-logging to learn how to see it.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for the logging part, very useful. The structure is very simple. but what happens is, it is doing SELECT for every time I do the assignment (that's what I got from logging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guess is that the main query loads only instances of `Parent` from the database, and when access the `parent.child` property, a separate `SQL` statement is generated for each `Parent` instance in order to read `Child` data from the database. As a result, you end up with `10K + 1` queries.

A way to improve here would be to use [Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#eager-loading). 
For 1-1 relationships a good option is `joinedload`:

```
q = session.query(Parent).options(joinedload(Parent.child))
```